# how to make docker pull the latest version each time the docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible for `docker-compose` file to pull the latest version each time I run `docker-compose up`

I now I can execute the `pull` command before the `compose up`. but I look to shortcut the steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is unfortunately not possible.

It's [a widely requested feature that has been refused by the docker compose developers](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3574).

Answer (score 3):

Try with `docker-compose pull && docker-compose up`

Comment: if you read my question carefully, my goal is to not use `docker-compose pull`
each time I run `docker-compose up`

Comment: Right, this PR was merged few months ago: https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/1498/files seems it might solve the issue if you can embed it in `docker-compose.yaml`

Comment: The above PR introduced a flag `--pull` which enables three different policies for pulling container images (namely always,never,missing). A sample command that can be issued is `docker run --pull=always python3:latest` which will try to pull the container every time the container is run.

Still, no release has been made with the above change. Also, for the moment `docker-compose` does not seem to support such flag.

Comment: It appears that `docker-compose up` now offers a `--pull` flag. See the [`docker-compose up` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/) under the "Options" table.